# Cuando uso Count y group by se dividen los resultados y no suma

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy tratando de hacer query que me obtenga la cantidad de id_conductor que se repiten en la consulta, se que es muy facil pero estoy teniendo problemas con el group by.
Query inicial:

```
SELECT 
r.ID_CONDUCTOR,
COUNT(r.id_conductor) as pedidos,
id_externo
FROM apidelprd.TB_API_EVENT_BRINGG  r
where 
 FECHA_OPERACION>=to_date('19/04/2022','DD/MM/YYYY') 
 and  FECHA_OPERACION<to_date('20/04/2022','DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY r.id_conductor,id_externo
```

Este query es el que quisiera agregarle la columna de count id_conductor con esas columnas:

```
SELECT
ID_EXTERNO,
TITULO,
TITULO_PARTE_1,
TITULO_PARTE_2,
TITULO_PARTE_3,
FECHA_OPERACION AS FECHA_HORA ,to_char(FECHA_OPERACION,'DD/MM/YYYY') as FECHA_OPERACION,
COUNT(ID_CONDUCTOR),
NOMBRE_CONDUCTOR,
ID_EXTERNO_CONDUCTOR,
ID_ESTADO,
case(ID_ESTADO) 
       when 7 then 'ANULADO PRE' 
       when 10 then 'ANULADO POST'
       when 4 then case(TITULO_PARTE_3)
            when '1' then 'CLIENTE CON METODO DE PAGO INCORRECTO' 
            when '2' then 'DRIVER EN PUERTA NO ATENDIDO' 
            when '3' then 'ENVIOS CAR' 
            when '4' then 'VENTAS CORPORATIVAS'      
            when '5' then 'PEDIDO NO SALTÓ A BRINGG'
            when '6' then 'PEDIDOS MUY GRANDES'
            when '7' then 'ERROR EN LA DIRECCION PEDIDO FZ'
            ELSE 'COMPLETADO' END 
         else 'OTROS'
END COMENTARIO
,INICIO_PEDIDO
 ,FIN_PEDIDO
 FROM apidelprd.TB_API_EVENT_BRINGG  r
where 
 FECHA_OPERACION>=to_date('19/04/2022','DD/MM/YYYY') --- modificar de acuerdo a solicitud de OPS
 and  FECHA_OPERACION<to_date('20/04/2022','DD/MM/YYYY') --- modificar de acuerdo a solicitud de OPS
GROUP BY ID_EXTERNO,
TITULO,
TITULO_PARTE_1,
TITULO_PARTE_2,
TITULO_PARTE_3,
FECHA_OPERACION,
ID_CONDUCTOR,
NOMBRE_CONDUCTOR,
ID_EXTERNO_CONDUCTOR,
ID_ESTADO,
INICIO_PEDIDO,
FIN_PEDIDO
```

Cuando solo pongo la columna id_conductor, y en el group by le pongo lo mismo id_conductor, genial funciona, pero le tengo que poner mas columnas, cuando le voy agregando las demas columnas en el select y luego en el group by porque el pl/sql me obliga a poner, se dividen los resultados:

**Se divide los resultados y no los cuenta**

[image]

**EN CAMBIO SI SOLO LE PONGO ESA SOLA COLUMNA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecere puedan ilumnarme, quuisierame colocarle mas columnas